# Подробная информация об устройстве на ОС Android

Tags: информация, android-sdk, android, java

Требуется получить максимальные характеристики: модель телефона, количество ядер, объем ОЗУ, объем жесткого диска, разрешение камеры и т.д., и т.п.
Могу получить только эту информацию, но она для меня не нужна(((

```
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    mText.append("\n\n Номер сборки ПО: " + Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL);
    mText.append("\n Версия Android: " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
    mText.append("\n Версия SDK: " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);

    mText.append("\n\n    Информация о телефоне и sim карте");
    mText.append("\n----------------------------------------------------------");
    mText.append("\n Cостояние вызова телефона: " + TS.callState(tm.getCallState()));
    mText.append("\n Тип мобильного телефона: " + TS.phoneType(tm.getPhoneType()));
    mText.append("\n Тип сотовой сети: " + TS.networkType(tm.getNetworkType()));
    mText.append("\n Код страны, в которой зарегистрирован оператор: " + tm.getNetworkCountryIso());
    mText.append("\n Код оператор (MCC+MNC) (mobile country code + mobile network code): " + tm.getNetworkOperator());
    mText.append("\n Имя оператора: " + tm.getNetworkOperatorName());
    mText.append("\n ID мобильного устройства: " + tm.getDeviceId());
    mText.append("\n Версия программного обеспечения (это не версия android): " + tm.getDeviceSoftwareVersion());
    mText.append("\n Состояние передачи данных: " + TS.dataState(tm.getDataState()));
    mText.append("\n Направление передачи данных: " + TS.dataActivity(tm.getDataActivity()));
    mText.append("\n Телефон находится в роуминге: " + (tm.isNetworkRoaming() ? "true" : "false"));

    mText.append("\n\n Состояние sim-карты: " + TS.simState(tm.getSimState()));
    mText.append("\n Код страны провайдера: " + tm.getSimCountryIso());
    mText.append("\n Код оператора (MCC+MNC): " + tm.getSimOperator());
    mText.append("\n Имя провайдера: " + tm.getSimOperatorName());
    mText.append("\n Серийный номер sim-карты: " + tm.getSimSerialNumber());
    mText.append("\n########################################");

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    mText.append("\n\n    Информация о дисплее");
    mText.append("\n----------------------------------------------------------");
    mText.append("\n Плотность пикселей на экране (dpi): " + metrics.densityDpi);
    mText.append("\n Фактор масштабирования для шрифтов: " + metrics.scaledDensity);
    mText.append("\n Высота экрана: " + metrics.heightPixels);
    mText.append("\n Ширина экрана: " + metrics.widthPixels);
    mText.append("\n Точное количество пикселей на дюйм по длине экрана: " + metrics.xdpi);
    mText.append("\n Точное количество пикселей на дюйм по ширине экрана: " + metrics.ydpi);
    mText.append("\n########################################");

    mText.append("\n Количество ядер: " +
            Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
```

Comment: @klim0v, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @klim0v, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что то подобное, попробуйте...

```
System.getProperty("os.version");  
android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK       
android.os.Build.DEVICE           
android.os.Build.MODEL             
android.os.Build.PRODUCT
```